# Add API connections in parameters file dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have a scenario where i have to send a mail using outlook connector. While developing logic app, i have given credentials. Now i want to give it as a product to some one. How will i be able to take inputs from user , create api connection and use it in logic app? I have looked into ARM template but not able to get clear idea how api connection can be dynamically added. Many tutorials are showing about url or constants which are kept in parameters file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the Outlook connector API authorisation works with the OAuth 2.0 `Authorisation Code` Grant Type, which means, you can only get the authorisation code by getting the user owning the mailbox (or having access to the shared mailbox) to sign in to get the code (token). This behaviour of the Outlook API is by design because the authentication is in the context of a user. Thus, ATM there is no way to fully automate it.

HTH